# Gerar código de barras padrão 2 de 5 intercalado em java

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Bom dia, estou tentando implementar um gerador de código de barras para poder gerar o código para pagamento de um boleto do tipo arrecadação.

Pesquisando percebi precisava ser no padrão 2 de 5 intercalado, a forma como eu fiz esta no padrão **code128** e eu não sei e não encontrei como fazer no padrão a cima.

**Alguém conhece como gerar nesse padrão**?

OBS.: A biblioteca que estou usando no Java e a Barcode.

Este e o trecho do código que eu tenho:

```
    public static BufferedImage generateEAN13BarcodeImage(String barcodeText) {
        Code128 barcodeGenerator = new Code128();
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = 
          new BitmapCanvasProvider(160, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);
     
        barcodeGenerator.generateBarcode(canvas, barcodeText);
        return canvas.getBufferedImage();
    }
```

desde já agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, consegui resolver. no caso bastou instanciar um objeto com **Interleaved2Of5Bean**  Vou deixar registrado para quem tiver essa duvida.

```
    public static BufferedImage generateBarcodeImage(String barcodeText) {
        Interleaved2Of5Bean barcodeGenerator = new Interleaved2Of5Bean();
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = 
          new BitmapCanvasProvider(160, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);
     
        barcodeGenerator.generateBarcode(canvas, barcodeText);
        return canvas.getBufferedImage();
    }
```